# Run libpcap without sudo/root

Tags: c++, linux, root, sudo, libpcap

I am using libpcap to sniff packets and also to create raw packets in C++ in Ubuntu 18.04. These features require admin(sudo) permission. I am checking for a way to remove the dependency.

When I run my code without sudo, I get the following error:
`pcap_open_live(): You don't have permission to capture on that device (socket: Operation not permitted)`

I build my application using cmake and make and I have the executable `test`, which I run as `./test`.

I have tried `setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip ./test`, but without sudo, I am unable to capture packets, with the same permission error as above.

Please help on this issue.

Comment: you could either give the user special permissions via group (https://askubuntu.com/questions/530920/tcpdump-permissions-problem) or set your application to run as root (regardless of who executes it) via chmod.  both these require you to have admin to begin with.

Comment: You could use the [linux] tag, or ask on se.linux. I know that by modifyng the /etc/sudoers file, you can allow users to execute some particular  commands, without the command sudo. I don't know if it corresponds exactly to yours needs

Comment: @Abel I tried both the approaches, but still getting the error.

Comment: @Damien could u provide an example on the same

Comment: I am not an expert. I used it a long time ago. You can find some information here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers

Comment: the second method should achieve the same effect as running as root (or at least give you a different error at the chmod step if it is disabled).  it involves sudo chown root <executable> and sudo chmod u+s <executable>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/506766/why-is-cap-net-admin-insufficient-permissions-for-ioctltunsetiff).

Issue turned out to be my hard disk not mounted with sudo. I built my tool in home folder and with setcap, I am able to sniff packets without sudo now.